# There exists a linear transformation $S$ such that $V = N_T \oplus R_S$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I'm attempting to solve this problem:

> Let  $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces and  $T:V\to W$ be a surjective linear transformation. Show that there exists a linear transformation $S:W \to V$ such that
>
> $$ V = \text{null}\,{T} \oplus \text{range}\,{S}.$$

This is what I have tried: Because $T$ is surjective, $T$ is injective, thus $\text{null}\,T = \{0\}$. Therefore, $V = \{0\} \oplus \text{range}\,{S} = \text{range}\,{S}$. Let $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ be a basis of $V$ and $(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ be a basis of $W$ where $n=\text{dim}\,V$ and $m=\text{dim}\,W$. Then define $S$ to be $S(w_1,\dots,w_m) = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$. I'm not sure if this definition of $S$ satisfies  $V = \text{range}\,S$. If this selection of $S$ is not good, how should I define $S$ so that $V=\text{null}\,T\oplus\text{range}\,S$ ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is not given that V and W have the same dimension, so T need not be injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost get it right, but the reverse mapping needs more reasoning. $\mathcal T$ is not injective, but it would be injective if you restricted it to a smaller subspace. Thus we proceed as follows.

Let $\dim(V) = n, \dim(W) = m$. By Rank-nullity theorem
$$
\dim(\mathrm {Ker}(\mathcal T)) + \dim (\mathrm {Im} (\mathcal T)) = \dim (V),
$$
we have $r + m = n \geqslant m$, where $r \colon = \dim(\mathrm {Ker}(\mathcal T))$. Pick up a basis $(\alpha_j)_1^r$ in $\mathrm {Ker}(\mathcal T)$, and extend it to a basis $(\alpha_j)_1^{m+r}$. Then the dimension of $U \colon = \mathrm {span}(\alpha_j)_{r+1}^{r+m}$ is $m$, and $$V = N \oplus U [N = \mathrm {Ker}(\mathcal T)].$$ Then for every $\alpha \in V$, there exists a unique pair of vectors $\nu \in N, \upsilon \in U : \alpha = \nu + \upsilon $, hence $\mathcal T\alpha = \mathcal T \upsilon$. This implies that $$\mathrm {Im }(\mathcal T) = \mathrm {Im }(\mathcal T|_U) = W.$$ Thus $\mathcal T|_U $ is surjective. Since $\dim(U) = \dim(W)$, $\mathcal T|_U$ is actually bijective hence invertible. Then let $\mathcal S = (\mathcal T|_U)^{-1}$, and we have $\mathrm{Im}(\mathcal S) = U$, and $$V = N \oplus U = \mathrm {Ker}(\mathcal T) \oplus \mathrm {Im }(\mathcal S)$$ as desire.

P.S. if you have learned about quotient spaces and quotient transformations, the proof above would be easier to understand.